# How to change text of kivy label from python file?

Tags: python, variables, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Cant find the answer to the this problem. Have looked at similar posts but they did not work for me here is a short snippets of the code that I think I have to work on

```
points="12"
class MainApp(MDApp):
    root.ids.points_label = points
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")

MainApp().run()
```

KV:

```
MDFloatLayout:

    MDLabel:
        text: 
        id: points_label
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```

I am also using KivyMD so that might have a effect on the process, I don't know.
Been stuck on this for a while hope you can help.

Goal:
Trying to set a variable to a labels text in kivy MD.

Here is the code after the suggested edits but it is now showing a blank kivymd screen. Here is the code`that is needed:

```
points = "12"
class MyFloatLayout(MDFloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.point_label_text = points

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")
```

INFO: Points equals 12 only for this example
KV:

```
<MyFloatLayout>
    MDLabel:
        text: root.point_label_text
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```

This code is still not working here is the import in the python file for the kivymd class incase that is the problem

```
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
```

Hope you can get some answers from my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a custom class of MDFloatLayout and from it you can assign it your points variable, and reference it in kv
For example:

**.py**

```
class MyFloatLayout(MDFloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.point_label_text = points
```

**.kv**

```
<MyFloatLayout>
    MDLabel:
        text: root.point_label_text
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```